# change the return of to_param by action? or, terribly broken edit action if perma-url is returned instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, field, permalinks

I did some stuff to have `to_param` return a perma-url so I'd have seo friendly links. Upon creation and update it will generate and return the perma-url in a `to_param` method that I put in the model. However this causing me some grief in other areas. I have a form that looks like this:

```
   <% @apps.each do |app| %>

   <% fields_for "[id][]", app  do |fields| %>
      ....
```

this fails terribly since it tries to insert the perma-url in place of the id. If I could just restrict `to_param` by action, that could solve things. If I change app to app.id, that fails since I have stuff like this:  `fields.check_box :is_featured` . I suppose I could get the app instance, but that feels hacky.

Again please excuse my lack of rails-foo ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not seo friendly it is human friendly

And about problems with fields_for — try to use latest rails version and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: Well if it's human friendly, it's SEO friendly since it's easier to index.

The situation is that I want to batch update several application objects. I know about accepts nested attributes for but I don't think it's a good idea to put that on the app object.

Comment: You have page with form for several application objects and nothing that has_many of them?

Comment: No. they're just a bunch of individual application objects that I wanted to bulk edit on one page. the previous code worked fine before I put in the permalink